# What is the meaning of 妖星?

Tags: translation, word, word-requests, idioms

I'm trying to make sense of the word 妖星 ("demon star") which I have encountered in a Japanese phrase. This word does not appear in any Japanese or Chinese (English) dictionaries I've run across, but searching for the word on Google turns up a number of hits in Chinese sites (especially https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A6%96%E6%98%9F which appears to be a dictionary definition). However I don't speak/read Chinese, and auto-translations of that page (e.g. https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=https://baike.baidu.com/item/%25E5%25A6%2596%25E6%2598%259F&prev=search) are such broken English all I can really tell is that it's an idiom that seems to reference Taoist astrology. What is the meaning of this term (both astrologically and idiomatically) - or at least enough information that I could look up more information on English reference sites (right now I don't even have a good enough English translation of the word to look it up on English sites)?

Comment: present site is for "finer points of the Chinese language", **bkrs** ：古以彗星隐现不常，故称为「妖星」。
左传．昭公十年：「居其维首，而有妖星焉。」
或作「祅星」。
yāoxīng
star of evil omens; comet
古代指预兆灾祸的星，如彗星等。
**iciba** :释义  1. 古代指预兆灾祸的星，如彗星等。
例句  蔡州 城中众心死，妖星夜落照河水。& there is more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, "妖星" is a category name of observable astronomical / meteorological  phenomenons, those are assigned as "bad omen".

in the book "靈臺秘苑" by 庾季才, in volume 15, it was defined as:

[靈臺秘苑　卷十三⋯卷十五　page 195](https://archive.org/stream/06065990.cn#page/n195/mode/1up)

> 妖星者﹒五行五星之變﹒天地惡氣之所生也

roughly, means "evil star (妖星), the so called (者), [is] the rebels of (之變) five elements (五行), [and / or] five planets (五星), produced (生) by (所) the bad force (惡氣) from the sky and earth (天地)"

[image]

afterward, the author listed 40+ entries in this category "妖星", an interesting point is:

"彗星", "孛星" & "長星", comets;  & "客星", nova; are also listed as "妖星"

i would suggest you find someone who can read literary chinese, and understand astrology / astronomy to help you. the google translate cannot handle literary chinese, the link provided is, . . . :(

last, the english book "stars of jade" by julius d w staal, would give you some basic ideas about "chinese astronomy".

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

妖星 can be found in, at least, two Chinese to English dictionaries:

**ABC**

> star of evil omens; comet

**KEY**

> unlucky stars (novae, comets, etc.)

and even one Chinese to French dictionary:

**GR**

> Étoile néfaste; comète.

There is the idea, that is popular is some astrological circles, that certain stars can have certain negative effects on people and their behavior. Comets, also, have been seen as bad omens in many cultures throughout history.

Answer (score 0):

妖星in Chinese has another meaning aside from astrology, it means a new and very young athlete, usually a football player.
But im sure in Japanese it is just a symbol of something bad